# Unable to push docker image to amazon ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I am new to docker. I want to use ECR private repository for storing my docker images. So I have built my docker image and did run it on local. I am using CLI. Then created a repository say artle/repo on ECR with full access control on pushing/pulling images. Then loggedin to my aws account and when I try to push my image from local to artle/repo, small files are getting pushed but large files (say 349Mb) are getting stuck in middle of pushing. It does not give any error. It continuously shows "pushing [=====>       ] 42.MB/349MB". I tried pushing some open source images also by thinking may be some error is there with my image, but got the same result.

```
  The push refers to a repository [111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ubuntu]
  5f70bf18a086: Pushed
  6f32b23ac95d: Pushed
  14d918629d81: Pushed
  fd0e26195ab2: Pushing [===========>                                       ]  42.4 MB/187.8 MB
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is likely a networking issue. Your steps are correct so far. Try from a different network.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting docker-machine fixed problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and it turned out the EC2 I was on had an old version of docker. There was no error, it just died trying to transfer stuff. Eventually I found an error buried in some system log that mentioned that my docker version was deprecated so I updated Docker and everything magically worked.

In a nutshell: try using the latest ECS optimized image for your region from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html and see if that fixes the problem.